# How do you fix a error like this? in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, geolocation, location

```dart
      static Future<DirectionDetails?> obtainDirectionsDetails(LatLng initialPosition, LatLng finalPosition) async {
    String directionURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?destination=${finalPosition.latitude},${finalPosition.longitude}&origin=${initialPosition.latitude},${initialPosition.longitude}&key=$mapKey";
    var res = await RequestAssistant.getRequest(directionURL);

    if(res == "failed"){
      return null;
    }

    DirectionDetails directionDetails = DirectionDetails();

    directionDetails.encodedPoints = res["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"][0]["points"];

    directionDetails.distanceText = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["text"];
    directionDetails.distanceValue = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"];

    directionDetails.durationText = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"]["text"];
    directionDetails.durationValue = res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"]["value"];

    return directionDetails;

  }
}

    Future<void> getPlaceDirection() async {
    var initialPos = await Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).pickUpLocation;
    var finalPos =  await Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).dropOffLocation;

    var pickUpLatLng =  LatLng(initialPos?.latitude ?? 0.0, initialPos?.longtitude ?? 0.0);
    var dropOffLatLng =  LatLng(finalPos?.latitude ?? 0.0, finalPos?.longtitude ?? 0.0);

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => ProgressDialog(message: "Please Wait...",)
    );

    DirectionDetails? details = await AssistantMethods.obtainDirectionsDetails(pickUpLatLng, dropOffLatLng);

    Navigator.pop(context);

    print("This is Encoded Points ::");
    print(details!.encodedPoints);

    PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
    List<PointLatLng> decodedPolylinePointsResult =  polylinePoints.decodePolyline(details.encodedPoints!);

    plineCordinates.clear();

    if(decodedPolylinePointsResult.isNotEmpty){
      decodedPolylinePointsResult.forEach((PointLatLng pointLatLng) {
        plineCordinates.add(LatLng(pointLatLng.latitude, pointLatLng.longitude));
      });
    }

    polylineSet.clear();

    setState(() {
      Polyline polyline = Polyline(
        color: Colors.pink,
        polylineId: PolylineId("PolylineID"),
        jointType: JointType.round,
        points: plineCordinates,
        width: 5,
        startCap: Cap.roundCap,
        endCap: Cap.roundCap,
        geodesic: true,
      );
      polylineSet.add(polyline);
    });
  }}
```

This is The Error:

```
E/flutter (31372): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter (31372): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:260:36)
E/flutter (31372): #1      AssistantMethods.obtainDirectionsDetails (package:rider_app/Assistants/assistantMethods.dart:48:51)
E/flutter (31372): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31372): #2      _MainScreenState.getPlaceDirection (package:rider_app/AllScreens/mainscreen.dart:361:33)
E/flutter (31372): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: The error message means that you're trying to access an element of an empty `List`.  You haven't provided enough information to easily discern exactly where you do that; you will need to isolate and debug that yourself.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Example of what?  How to debug a program?  Your first step should be to look at the lines referred to by the stacktrace and to identify where the exception came from.  Then navigate backwards through the callers to figure out what caused it.